# target_include_directories - INTERFACE doesn't export an include path

Tags: cmake

I have created a very simple cmake project for testing cmake features. The project directory contains two libraries. I would like to export MyLibA include path.

The main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(TestProject)

add_subdirectory(MyLibA)
add_subdirectory(MyLibB)
```

MyLibA CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(MyLibA SHARED)     
target_sources(MyLibA PRIVATE fileA.h fileA.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyLibA INTERFACE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/MyLibA")
```

MyLibB CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(MyLibB SHARED)

target_sources(MyLibB PRIVATE fileB.h fileB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE /home/user/MyProjects/CmakeTestProject/build/MyLibA/libMyLibA.so)
```

I have exported an include path using INTERFACE keyword but the following include in fileB.h:

`#include "fileA.h"`

is not found. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Instead of `target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE <path/to/MyLibA/file>)` use `target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE MyLibA)`. This is how CMake is intended to be used: when link with the library **target**, CMake automatically transforms that into the path and actually propagates all interface properties of the target.

Comment: Works, please transform your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE <path/to/MyLibA/file>)
```

use

```
target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE MyLibA)
```

This is how CMake is intended to be used: when link with the library **target**, CMake automatically transforms that into the path and actually propagates all interface **properties** of the target.

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

Several things:

1. **Never** put absolute paths in your CMakeLists.txt and **always** link to *targets* rather than *library files*.

```
# Linking to a target propagates usage requirements, like include paths.
target_link_libraries(MyLibB PRIVATE MyLibA)
```

2. **`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`** is not what you think. It refers always to the *top-level* build directory, which is a bad assumption if your project might be an `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent` target. Your usage can be replaced by:

```
# Not optimal, see below.
target_include_directories(MyLibA INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

3. Missing `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` on include path, if you intend to export your targets. When targets are exported, their properties are copied verbatim to the output. Not guarding the local include path with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` will break users of the exported target.

```
target_include_directories(
  MyLibA 
  INTERFACE
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
)
```